# javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement

Tags: java, hibernate, servlets

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFXFe.png)I am implementing application when user login in the application the username and password will stored in the database I kept username as private key(I am using hibernate)but when the user login in the second time it will throwing error how can I handle this any suggestions,Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your implementation is a little bit ambiguous why you store username/password every time the user login-in. that, will obviously raise an exception (constraint violation) if the username is designed as a Primary Key in the database.
instead try to store username and password at the sign-up step and then every time user try to login-in you will just verify that username/password exist in the database.

Comment: Yes,Thank you so much I did like that only.